# Outputting Data into an HTML table using php/html

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to output data onto my webpage from a database. I am able to so successfully, but in a very untidy way. I have tried to put the data in a table on the website with no success.

Below, data is retrieved from the db, but just echoed out crudely. It looks untidy but it outputs successfully onto the webpage

```
 <?php
        $query = "SELECT name, email, address FROM SHHowners";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "Name: " . $row["name"] . " - Email: " . $row["email"] . " - Address: " . $row["address"] . "<br>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "0 results";
        }


        mysqli_close($conn);
```

I try to put the data into an HTML table(on the same page, by combining PHP and HTML with no success. How can put this data into an organised table successfully?

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><?php $row["name"] ?></td>
        <td><?php $row["email"] ?></td>
        <td><?php $row["address"]?></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Below is roughly how I would like the data to be structured, how can achieve this?

```
Name  | Email | Address
Jo    |J@o.com|12 Street
Ben   |B@e.com|23 street
```

Comment: Your attempt at outputting the table got rid of *all of the PHP*.  Where's the loop?  Where are the `echo` statements?  You can take the exact structure you have in your working code and just put the HTML structure where you need it.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
<?php 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php $row["name"] ?></td>
        <td><?php $row["email"] ?></td>
        <td><?php $row["address"]?></td>
      </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
    <?php
      $query  = "SELECT name, email, address FROM SHHowners";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
      if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
          <td><?php $row["name"]?></td>
          <td><?php $row["email"]?></td>
          <td><?php $row["address"]?></td>
      <?php }
          } ?>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
        $query = "SELECT name, email, address FROM SHHowners";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Bordered Table</h2>
  <p>The .table-bordered class adds borders to a table:</p>            
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Address</th>
      </tr>
    </thead> <tbody>
<?php
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php $row["name"] ?></td>
        <td><?php $row["email"] ?></td>
        <td><?php $row["address"]?></td>
      </tr>
<?php            }
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td colspan=3>0 results</td></tr>";
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always print the results from the select like this:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   echo "<tr>
<td>".$row["name"]."</td>

<td>".$row["email"]."</td>

<td>".$row["address"] . "</td></tr>";

}
```

It's not a very clean way, but for each row *should* print another row, below the three table headers.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really a very neat way to do this beyond the other answers.

But what you can do is keep the `HTML` and `PHP` separate as much as possible in the same file.

The `PHP` at the top of the file can be as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT name, email, address FROM SHHowners";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

$htmlToDisplay = ''; //this variable will contain table rows

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   //create the HTML row - we'll use this later
   $htmlToDisplay .= "<tr><td>".$row['name']."</td><td>". $row['email']."</td><td>".$row['address']."</td></tr>";   
  }
} else {
  $htmlToDisplay = "<tr><td>0 results</td><tr>";
}
```

Then you can have your `HTML` after your closing `PHP` tag (`?>`) as follows:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Address</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- echo your php row(s) here in a slightly neater way since it's one line -->
    <?php echo $htmlToDisplay; ?> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This will make the the different parts of the file (the `PHP` and `HTML`) more readable.

You could also look at using a PHP template engine like [smarty](http://www.smarty.net/).